# Items don't show up

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-room, android-viewmodel

Good morning , 
I've problem in my source code but there is no error .
 I'm creating a fragment with folder items using Room database and viewModel. My probleme is when I add new folder it doesn't show app in folderFragment even if add them in dataBase(i.e witouth pressing in add button).
 (i've used the same code in other activity and it works but here no result).

FolderFragment

```
public class AjouterDos_Fragment extends Fragment {
View view;
private DosViewModel dosViewModel;
private List<Dossier> listDos = new ArrayList<>();

public static final int ADD_DOS_REQUEST = 1;
private RecyclerView folder_recyclerView;
private FloatingActionButton btn_add_dos;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = 
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ajouter_dos_,container,false);

    btn_add_dos =  view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_dos);

    btn_add_dos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCustomDialog();

        }
    });

    folder_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.folder_recyclerView);

    folder_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    folder_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   // folder_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new 
    DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    final DosAdapter adapter1 = new DosAdapter();

    folder_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);


   dosViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DosViewModel.class);

    dosViewModel.insert(new Dossier(":3333333"));

    dosViewModel.getAllFolders().observe(this, new Observer<List<Dossier>> 
        () {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Dossier> dossiers) {
            //update RecyclerView
            adapter1.setDossiers(dossiers);

        }
    });
    return view ;
      }



     private void showCustomDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // before
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_add_edit_dos);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
    ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    final Button add_dos = (Button) 
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_fold_btn);
    final Button back = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

    final EditText titre = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.titre);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //toast.cancel();
        }
    });
    add_dos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dossier dos = new Dossier(titre.getText().toString());
            dosViewModel.insert(dos);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}
 }
```

FolderViewModel

```
 public class DosViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private DosRepository dosRepository;

private LiveData<List<Dossier>> dossiers;

public DosViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    dosRepository = new DosRepository(application);
    dossiers = dosRepository.getAllFolders();
}

public void insert(Dossier dossier) { dosRepository.insert(dossier); }

public void update(Dossier dossier) {
    dosRepository.update(dossier);
}

public void delete(Dossier dossier) {
    dosRepository.delete(dossier);
}

public void deleteAllFolders() { dosRepository.deleteAllFolders(); }

public LiveData<List<Dossier>> getAllFolders() {
    return dossiers;
}
}
```

FolderRepository

```
public class DosRepository {

private DosDAO dosDAO;

private LiveData<List<Dossier>> dossiers;

public DosRepository(Application application) {
    DB_MJG database = DB_MJG.getInstance(application);

    dosDAO= database.dosDAO();
    dossiers = dosDAO.getAllFolders();
}

public void insert(Dossier dossier) {
    new InsertDosAsyncTask(dosDAO).execute(dossier);
}

public void update(Dossier dossier) {
    new UpdateDosAsyncTask(dosDAO).execute(dossier);
}

public void delete(Dossier dossier) {
    new DeleteDosAsyncTask(dosDAO).execute(dossier);
}

public void deleteAllFolders() {
    new DeleteAllDosAsyncTask(dosDAO).execute();
}

public LiveData<List<Dossier>> getAllFolders() {
    return dossiers;
}


private static class InsertDosAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Dossier, Void, 
 Void> {
    private DosDAO dosDAO;

    private InsertDosAsyncTask(DosDAO dosDAO) {
        this.dosDAO =dosDAO;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Dossier... dossiers) {
        dosDAO.insert(dossiers[0]);
        return null;
    }


}

private static class UpdateDosAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Dossier, Void, 
 Void> {
    private DosDAO dosDAO;

    private UpdateDosAsyncTask(DosDAO dosDAO) {
        this.dosDAO = dosDAO;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Dossier... dossiers) {
        dosDAO.update(dossiers[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteDosAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Dossier, Void, 
 Void> {
    private DosDAO dosDAO;

    private DeleteDosAsyncTask(DosDAO dosDAO) {
        this.dosDAO = dosDAO;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Dossier... dossiers) {
        dosDAO.delete(dossiers[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteAllDosAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, 
 Void> {
    private DosDAO dosDAO;

    private DeleteAllDosAsyncTask(DosDAO dosDAO) {
        this.dosDAO = dosDAO;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        dosDAO.deleteAllFolders();
        return null;
     }
      }
  }
```

database

```
Database(entities = {Note.class,RDV.class, Dossier.class}, version = 2)
public abstract class DB_MJG  extends RoomDatabase {

private static DB_MJG instance;

public abstract NoteDAO noteDao();
public abstract DosDAO dosDAO(); 


public static  synchronized DB_MJG getInstance(Context context)
{
    if(instance==null){
        instance = Room.

   databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),DB_MJG.class,"MJGbd")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new 
  RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
       new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
    }
};
    private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, 
  Void> 
  {
    private NoteDAO noteDAO;
    private DosDAO dosDAO;
    private PopulateDbAsyncTask(DB_MJG db) {
        noteDAO = db.noteDao();
        dosDAO = db.dosDAO();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            noteDAO.insert(new Note("20/05/2019", "23:50", "Je t'aime my 
      liitle boy"));
            noteDAO.insert(new Note("21/05/2019", "23:50", "Je t'aime my 
      liitle girl"));
            dosDAO.insert(new Dossier(":3"));
        dosDAO.insert(new Dossier("Zmer"));
      return null;
    }
}

   }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `adapter1.setDossiers(dossiers);` is not called in `onChanged` method? Can you once check by printing any value or debugging if the problem is in the adapter or in the `ViewModel`.

Comment: The problem Ih in the viewModel but I don’t know Why cause when I print the elements of the list (dossiers)  it’s not empty and when I try to add some data to the list (listdos) then I use adapter witouht using view model it works . So I didn’t understand where is the prob .

Comment: So I think the problem is on the onChanged method .